# Regex to extract 2nd and 3rd string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to extract the 2nd and 3rd string from a sentence with space being always be the delimiter.
E,g - my sentence is "Regex is new for me". I need "is new" as my output.

I have the below Regex which is working when i try in regex101 site.

```
 (?<=\s)(.*?)(?=\s) (?<=\s)(.*?)(?=\s)
```

I am thinking if this can be achieved in a better way using a different expression.

Comment: Try word boundaries? e.g. `/\b.+\b/`

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you ask for a regex solution?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl What you've provided is in essence the same as `^.+$`.  It just selects everything.  The first word boundary matches the start of line, then you have a greedy match for any character (which will match as much as it needs to), then you have another word boundary, which will match the end of line.  I suspect you meant to post something like `\b\w+\b`, which can then just be simplified down to `\w+`, since the word boundaries are redundant.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl, My application UI only supports Regex. Java script or any other script is not an option for me!

Comment: @Charlie Armstrong The REgex suggested is matching everything. I just need to match 2nd and 3rd String and not even the space between it, but just the strings. Regex i have is matching the space between the strings as well which i am trying to eliminate.. Can you let me know how i can just match the 2nd string ?

Comment: The only way I know of to do what you're asking is to use capturing groups, which your proposed regex already seems to use.  Can you use capturing groups?  If so, what is wrong with the regex you already have (other than just being very long and slow)?  Or are you asking for improvements on an already working regex?

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong, I am reading about capturing groups and it seems its the way.
The issue i have with my Regex or one Than LUONG has suggested (which is short and quick!) is it's matching the space as well in between 2nd and 3rd sting. I don't need to match the space in between. I just need words "is" and "new" to be matched (without matching space in between).

Comment: Could you just use something simple like ` (.+?) (.+?) `?  Capturing group 1 will be "is" and capturing group 2 will be "new".  Spaces will be included in the full match, but if you are using capturing groups you can just ignore the full match.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221526/discussion-between-abhinandan-aithal-and-charlie-armstrong).

Answer (score 3):

The easiest approach here is probably just to use `split`:

```js
var input = "Regex is new for me";
var parts = input.split(" ");
console.log("2nd term: " + parts[1]);
console.log("3rd term: " + parts[2]);
var combined = parts[1] + " " + parts[2];
console.log("combined: " + combined);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match a sequence of non-space characters, slice the results, and re-join them.

```js
console.log('Regex is new for me'.match(/\S+/g)
  .slice(1, 3).join(' '));

/**
 * @param {String} str    Sequence of words to split
 * @param {int}    start  Starting index
 * @param {int}    end    Ending index
 */
const subwords = (str, start, end) => str.match(/\S+/g)
  .slice(start, end).join(' ');
console.log(subwords('Regex is new for me', 1, 3));

/**
 * @param {String}  str     Sequence of words to split
 * @param {int}     count   Number of words to keep
 * @param {[int=0]} offset  Initial word offset
 */
const subwords2 = (str, count, offset=0) => str.match(/\S+/g)
  .slice(offset, offset + count).join(' ');
console.log(subwords2('Regex is new for me', 2, 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it. I get all words and the join 2nd and 3rd.

```js
var str = document.querySelector("#Phrase").textContent,
    words = str.match(/(\w+)/g),
    result = [];
    
result.push(words[1]);
result.push(words[2]);

document.querySelector("#ResultPhrase").textContent = result.join(" ");
```

```html
<p id="Phrase">Regex is new for me</p>
<p id="ResultPhrase"></p>
```

Comment: No need to use jQuery when you have `document.querySelector`. I went ahead and removed the dependency.

Comment: Thanks for edit it, I'm not good at pure Javascript

Comment: If you take a look at modern JS projects e.g. React, there is a lot of neat things you can accomplish with ES6 code. Just take some time and explore.

Answer (score 0):

You could use following regex.

```
(?<=\s)\w+\s\w+
```

**Note**: We do not use any options of regex. We get first match.

```js
var string = "Regex is new for me";
var result = string.match(/(?<=\s)\w+\s\w+/);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```js
const result = (string.match(/^\s*\S+\s+(\S+\s\S+)/) || ['', ''])[1];
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YNVkyY/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\S+` - one or more non-whitespaces
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(\S+\s\S+)` - Group 1: one or more non-whitespaces, one or more whitespaces, and one or more non-whitespaces

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const string = "Regex is new for me";
const result = (string.match(/^\s*\S+\s+(\S+\s\S+)/) || ['', ''])[1];
console.log(result); // => is new
```

If you *must* make sure you only match alphanumeric chars (not just any non-whitespace chars), you can replace `\S` with `[a-zA-Z0-9]` (for ASCII only support) or `[\p{N}\p{L}]` (with `u` flag, for the whole Unicode support):

```js
console.log( ("Regex is new for me".match(/^\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s+([a-zA-Z0-9]+\s[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/) || ['', ''])[1] );
```

Or

```js
console.log( ("Regex is new for me".match(/^\s*[\p{L}\p{N}]+\s+([\p{L}\p{N}]+\s[\p{L}\p{N}]+)/u) || ['', ''])[1] );
```